# Solving recurrence relation $T(n) = 2T(\sqrt n) + n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

> $$T(n) = 2T(\sqrt n) + n$$

I tried putting $n=2^m$:
$T(2^m) = 2T(2^(m/2)) + 2^m$.

If I subsitute $T(2^m) = S(m)$ then,
$S(m) = 2S(m/2) + 2^m$.

This is same as $$\sum^{\infty}_{x=0}2^{x+\frac m{2^x}}$$
Now I am stuck in this summation as it's not a GP.

Comment: Is $T(n)$ defined only when $n$ is a perfect square?

Comment: @ajotatxe Nothing like that.

Comment: What is the domain of $T$? Note that if $T(2)$ is defined, then so must be $T(\sqrt 2)$, $T(\sqrt[4]2)$, $T(\sqrt[8]2)$, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, asuming that every $T(n)$ is nonnegative, $T(n)\geqslant  n$.

Now, if $c>1$ and $n\geqslant16$, then $T(\sqrt n)\leqslant (c+1)\sqrt n$ implies $T(n)\leqslant n+2(c+1)\sqrt n\leqslant (c+1)n$ hence the property that $n\leqslant T(n)\leqslant (c+1)n$ is hereditary.

Thus, $T(n)=\Theta(n)$.

Comment: Did you get this equation $T(\sqrt n)\leqslant (c+1)\sqrt n$ by trying out for small values of n in the recurrence relation?

Comment: No, rather one notes that $T(n)\leqslant(c+1)n$ holds for every small $n$, if $c$ is large enough.